# ROS subscriber example (C++)

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every ROS users,

I followed the example as following link : [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.CA-c54953afb3f7ac20abfe7460208d0cd6c36c1d62_15)

But it not works when I type the command "rosrun beginner_tutorials", and it shows the message as this:

rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.
Does someone know the problem?
I would be thankful that anyone can help me. Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223117/ros-subscriber-example-(c++)/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The next tutorial in that sequence describes how to use rosrun to run the executable you're created: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-27**:
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command is:

```
rosrun <PACKAGE> <EXECUTABLE> [ARGS]
```

where angle and square brackets indicate *required* and *optional* items, respectively. According to what you've written, you've only done:

```
rosrun <PACKAGE>
```

and are missing the executable. You should be able to "tab-complete" (hit the TAB key twice in rapid succession) to get a list of valid executables.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1